# Insert one data to MySQL table without login

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface, mysql5

MySQL details:

```
MySQL username: root
MySQL password: z
```

To run MySQL query without login, the command is:

```
mysql -u root -pz -e "mysql-query-here"
```

So, if I want to create database with name `db1`, it will become:

```
mysql -u root -pz -e "CREATE DATABASE db1 CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin"
```

Now, I want to run this query for database `db1`

```
INSERT INTO `role_permission` VALUES (1,'create about_us content','node')
```

I dont know how to make it works. I've tried many combinations without luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the same command, but after adding the DB name like:

```
$ mysql -u root -p db1 -e "your-insert-here"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can just add a `use db1` command to the string you pass to mysql.

```
mysql -u root -pz -e "USE db1; INSERT INTO role_permissions values (1,'create about_us content','node');"
```

Also, did you create your `role_permissions` table e.g.

```
mysql -u root -pz -e "USE db1; CREATE TABLE role_permissions (id INT, data VARCHAR(200), type VARCHAR (10);"
```